# React Router based on dynamic context values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I hope all you are ding good.

I am developing a react(typescript) application in which I have to handle authentication and authorization.

I am following this pattern.
IAuthContext (will be loaded during startup or when user change their state)

```
export interface IAuthContext {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    isInitialized: boolean;
    user: firebase.User | null;
    permissions: object;
    landingPage: string;
    isOnBoardingCompleted: boolean;
}
```

Routes.js

```
const routerConfig = [
    {
        key: "key_",
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        isPrivate : false
    },
    {
        key: "dashboard",
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Frame,
        content: AnalyticsDashBoard,
        isPrivate : true
    },
```

App.tsx

```
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    {routes.map((route) =>{
                        return (route.isPrivate ?
                            <PrivateRoute {...route} exact/>
                            :
                            <Route path={route.path} component={route.component} key={route.key} exact/>)
                    })}
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

PrivateRoute.tsx

```
return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(routeProps) =>
                props.context.isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component {...routeProps} content={props.content}/>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: routeProps.location }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
```

Inside privateRoute I have access to role and permissions along with landing page(if user didnt complete registration after login, he has to be redirected to registration page). Also I need to give all possible combinations in privateroute based on authentication since it will load only once.

I tried to do this in private route

```
if (props.context.isAuthenticated && !props.context.isOnBoardingCompleted) {
        console.log("Going to redirect here to onboard--", props.context.landingPage);
        return <Route path={props.context.landingPage} component={OnBoarding}/>
    }
```

But this is not working since only the URL is changing. Also if the user is done with onboarding, I might not have a Route for it since all router controls already created with first-time values.
Please advise me on how can I handle this? All I need to do it is to have some sort of interceptor where I route/redirect to pages based on dynamic context values.

Expectation:
Just like scenario above, there are multiple roles and permissions and all those conditions should be checked here.

Answer (score 1):

`<Route path={props.context.landingPage} component={OnBoarding}/>` should be defined in your `Router` component.

You can use a nested ternary, though this can lead to readability issues.

```
return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={routeProps =>
      props.context.isAuthenticated ? (
        props.context.isOnBoardingCompleted ? (
          <Component {...routeProps} content={props.content} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/landing", // or "/onboard" whatever the route is
              state: { from: routeProps.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: routeProps.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: I thought of similar solution, but if I am not wrong this routes load once in the startup based on current context values. Once context changes, there is no longer need to go to onboarding, but we dont have route defined for that combo.

Comment: Does the `Router` have access to this "context" so it can conditionally render this "/onboard" route based upon `isOnBoardingCompleted` when it needs to? Otherwise it seems you have some unhealthy coupling of generic UI components to specific app use cases. Is there anything wrong with just *always* rendering an "/onboard" route? Is there something special and intrinsic about it to any users? Seems not based on it's API in your example as you were simply wanting to redirect to it.

Comment: Apologies since I dont get your statement completely. Bu tthe point is I need kinda interceptor/something with which based on context value I need to control the loading appropriately. 
i.e once user done with onboarding next time he can be redirected to the desired page, if he dont have access to the desired page, he can be redirected to his landing page. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Based upon the details given, this is exactly what the above code should do. If this isn't the desired behavior can you update your question with a bit more of your relevant app setup? The Router, app state/context, etc..

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese for your time. I just added expectation in the bottom and context structure as well.

Comment: @DrewReese this one is rendering two components at the same time.

Comment: @axfg Can you clarify your comment? `Route` components only render what is passed to them on either the `render`, `component`, or `children` props, or wrapped as children components.

Comment: @DrewReese I used two contexts as you described above with nested ternary. It is displaying the first component. And also displaying the landing component underneath it.

Comment: @axfg I don't really how that's possible with just a single route... are you rendering two of these private route components?

Comment: No. One is private and other is ordinary component. I use two contexts for authenticated user and subscribed user. I want to display the subscription form to unsubscribed user. But the above code displays home and subscription form both to a subscribed user.

Comment: @axfg I see. I think I need to see what your code is doing. It may be more beneficial to post a new question regarding your specific use-case and provide a relevant code example. You can reference this question. If you do post a question, ping me here with a link if you like and I'll take a look.

Comment: @DrewReese here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68573847/16334669

Answer (score 0):

May be you can organize your code like below. It will help you separate different routes and handles their role/auth checks in a clean readable manner.

```
function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route component={PublicContainer}/>
            <Route component={PrivateContainer}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const PrivateContainer = () => (
  <div>
    <NavBar/>
    <Switch>
      //routes with auth checks
    </Switch>
  </div>
);


const PrivateContainer = () => (
  <div>
    <NavBar/>
    <Switch>
      //Free routes
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```